# Localization of an extension of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, localization

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a ring morphism, $P$ a prime ideal of $B$. If $M$ is an $A$-module, then can we express $(M\otimes_A B)_P=M\otimes_A B_P$ as a tensor product over $A_{f^{-1}(P)}$? I would expect something like $M_{f^{-1}(P)}\otimes_{A_{f^{-1}(P)}} B_P$?

Comment: Let $p=f^{-1}(P)$. Then there is a morphism $A_p\to B_P$. Thus $M\otimes_AB_P=(M\otimes_AA_p)\otimes_{A_p}B_P$.

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3793463/394668).