# Proving that $(M \otimes_A N)_q = M_p \otimes_{A_p} N_q$ for a prime $q$ lying over $p$

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products, localization

Let $f : A \to B$ be a morphism between unital commutative rings. We can thus consider $B$-modules as $A$-modules via this map, and $A$-modules as $B$-modules via tensoring with $- \otimes_A B$.

Not let $M$ and $N$ be $A$- and $B$-modules respectively. Given a prime $q$ of $B$ and lying over a prime $p$ in $A$, we know that $f$ descends to a map between the respective localizations and so a similar correspondence as above holds for their respective modules.

> I want to show that
> $$
> M_p \otimes_{A_p} N_q \simeq (M \otimes_A N)_q,
> $$
> as $B_q$-modules.

My reasoning is as follows: since

$$
(M \otimes_A N)_q \simeq M \otimes_A N \otimes_B B_q \simeq M \otimes_A N_q,
$$

and $N_q$ is a $B_q$-module, it is an $A_p$-module, hence $N_q \simeq A_p \otimes_{A_p} N_q$ and therefore

$$
(M\otimes _A N)_q \simeq M \otimes_A A_p \otimes_{A_p} N_q \simeq M_p \otimes_{A_p} B_q.
$$

This sounds okay but I am using the "associativity of tensor product with respect to different rings" without caring much about it.

A sanity check and/or a reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like your concern is the justification that if $M$ is a right $A$-module, $N$ is a $(A,B)$-bimodule, and $L$ is a left $B$-module, then $(M\otimes_A N)\otimes_B L\cong M\otimes_A (N\otimes_B L)$. Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586211/associativity-of-tensor-products) answer your question?

Comment: I guess that, yes, that answers it; although I'd appreciate if you could look at my argument just in case there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Your argument works! The fact that the tensor product is "associative over multiple rings" is the content of my link, and your solution has simply applied this multiple times.

Comment: Awesome. Can you make the comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument works! You've simply applied the fact that if $f : A\to B$ is a ring morphism, $M$ is a right $A$-module, $N$ is a $(A,B)$-bimodule, and $L$ is a left $B$-module, then $(M\otimes_A N)\otimes_B L\cong M\otimes_A (N\otimes_B L)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586211/associativity-of-tensor-products)). Let us call this fact $(*).$ As you know, if $M$ is an $R$-module and $S\subseteq R$ is a multiplicative set, then $S^{-1}M\cong M\otimes_R S^{-1}R;$ call this fact $(**).$ Then your argument is the following computation:
\begin{align*}
(M\otimes_A N)_q &\cong (M\otimes_A N)\otimes_B B_q\qquad\quad\textrm{(using (**))}\\
&\cong M\otimes_A(N\otimes_B B_q)\qquad\quad\textrm{(using (*))}\\
&\cong M\otimes_A N_q\qquad\qquad\qquad\textrm{(using (**))}\\
&\cong M\otimes_A (A_p\otimes_{A_p} N_q)\qquad\textrm{because }R\otimes_R M\cong M\\
&\cong (M\otimes_A A_p)\otimes_{A_p} N_q\qquad\textrm{(using (*))}\\
&\cong M_p\otimes_{A_p} N_q\qquad\qquad\quad\textrm{(using (**))}.
\end{align*}

Comment: For posterity, here's the statement in full generality: Let $f:A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, $M$ be an $A$-module and $N$ be a $B$-module (which is also an $A$-module by restriction of scalars). If $T\subset B$ is a multiplicative subset of $B$, then $S=f^{-1}(T)$ is a multiplicative subset of $A$, the ring $T^{-1}B$ is a $S^{-1}A$-algebra, and we have isomorphisms of $T^{-1}B$-modules:
$$
T^{-1}(M\otimes_AN)
\cong M\otimes_AT^{-1}N
\cong S^{-1}M\otimes_{S^{-1}A}T^{-1}N.
$$
(*Mutatis mutandis*, the proof is the same as Stahl's one.)